# Unit Testing ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I'm unit testing a simple post:

```
public HttpResponseMessage<Document> PostDocument(Document document) 
{
    document = repository.Add(document); 

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage<Document>(document, HttpStatusCode.Created); 

    var uri = Url.Route(null, new { id = document.Id }); 

    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, uri); 

    return response; 
}
```

However, the 'URL' and 'Request' are obviously going to be null.

Is there an alternative to mocking out ControllerContext and HttpContext?

Update:

Changed it to:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage<Document> PostDocument(Document document,Uri location = null) 
{
    document = repository.Add(document); 

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage<Document>(document, HttpStatusCode.Created);

    if (location == null)
    {
        var uri = Url.Route(null, new { id = document.Id });
        location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, uri);
    }

    response.Headers.Location = location;

    return response; 
}
```

Update 2:

This is better:

```
public HttpResponseMessage<Document> PostDocument(Document document)
{
    var uri = Url.Route(null, new { id = document.Id });
    var location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, uri);

    return PostDocument(document, location);
}

[NonAction]
public HttpResponseMessage<Document> PostDocument(Document document, Uri location) 
{
    document = repository.Add(document); 

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage<Document>(document, HttpStatusCode.Created);
    response.Headers.Location = location;
    return response; 
}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042290/sample-code-for-unit-testing-api-controllers/22200520#22200520

Answer (score 1):

The `Request` property should be settable, so you only have to set the `ControllerContext` (which should have a no-arg constructor so you shouldn't even have to mock).

Answer (score 1):

Using FakeItEasy I got it to work doing this in the TestInitialize.

```
this.Controller.ControllerContext = new System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext();
this.Controller.Request = A.Fake<HttpRequestMessage>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method might recieve HttpRequestMessage as parameter.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage<Document> PostDocument(Document document, HttpRequestMessage message)
{

}
```

You can take RequestUri from it. In your unit tests you can put test double of HttpRequestMessage object.