# Sample code for unit testing api controllers

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

Is there an sample code that shows unit testing a controller that inherits from the api controller?
I am trying to unit test a POST but it is failing. I believe I need to set up the HttpControllerContext for testing but don't know how
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate question maybe?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483663/unit-testing-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 10):

this code should demonstrate the basics of a post test. Assumes you have a repository injected into the controller. I am using MVC 4 RC not Beta here if you are using Beta the Request.CreateResponse(... is a little different so give me a shout...

Given controller code a little like this:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    private IRepository<Foo> _fooRepository;

    public FooController(IRepository<Foo> fooRepository)
    {
        _fooRepository = fooRepository;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Foo value)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;

        Foo returnValue = _fooRepository.Save(value);
        response = Request.CreateResponse<Foo>(HttpStatusCode.Created, returnValue, this.Configuration);
        response.Headers.Location = "http://server.com/foos/1";

        return response;
    }
}
```

The unit test would look a little like this (NUnit and RhinoMock)

```
        Foo dto = new Foo() { 
            Id = -1,
            Name = "Hiya" 
        };

        IRepository<Foo> fooRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository<Foo>>();
        fooRepository.Stub(x => x.Save(dto)).Return(new Foo() { Id = 1, Name = "Hiya" });

        FooController controller = new FooController(fooRepository);

        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://server.com/foos");
        //The line below was needed in WebApi RC as null config caused an issue after upgrade from Beta
        controller.Configuration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration(new System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection());

        var result = controller.Post(dto);

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Created, result.StatusCode, "Expecting a 201 Message");

        var resultFoo = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Foo>().Result;
        Assert.IsNotNull(resultFoo, "Response was empty!");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, resultFoo.Id, "Foo id should be set");
```

Comment: Your post inadvertently uncovered a small bug in my code. I'd left off the third parameter to CreateResponse(..., this.Configuration). As soon as I added it, my null Configuration for my request object was no longer an issue. Hope this helps someone else who's looking

Comment: Setting configuration by 'controller.Configuration = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration(new System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection());' returned null in my action response returning line, so I've tried this :
controller.Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration()); and it worked.

Comment: -1 That's a horrific quantity of code to put in a unit test. [There are better tools](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22200520/11635)

Answer (score 1):

Using [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture), I usually do something like this:

```
[Theory, AutoCatalogData]
public void PostToCollectionReturnsCorrectResponse(
    CategoriesController sut,
    CategoryRendition categoryRendition)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = sut.Post(categoryRendition);

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Created, response.StatusCode);
}
```

See [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20723447/126014) for more details about this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for unit testing API controller with async fundtion in C#

1. Prepare test Models:

   ```
           using System;
           namespace TestAPI.Models
           {
               public class TestResult
               {
                   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
                   public bool Success { get; set; }
                   public string Message { get; set; }
               }      
           }
   ```
2. Prepare test controller

   ```
           using TestAPI.Models;
           using System;
           using System.Net;
           using System.Threading.Tasks;
           using System.Web.Http;
           using System.Web.Http.Description;

           namespace TestAPI.Controllers
           {   
               public class TestController : ApiController
               {       
                   public TestController()
                   {           
                   }

                   [HttpPost]
                   [ResponseType(typeof(TestResult))]
                   [Route("api/test/start")]
                   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> StartTest()
                   {                                
                       DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
                       var testProcessor = new TestAsync();
                       await testProcessor.StartTestAsync();                                     

                       HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                       return Content(statusCode, new TestResult
                       {
                           Date = DateTime.Now,
                           Success = true,
                           Message = "test"
                       }); 
                   }       

               }
           }
   ```
3. unit test async controller with result check from response

   ```
           using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
           using TestAPI.Controllers;
           using TestAPI.Models;
           using System.Web.Http;
           using System.Threading.Tasks;
           using System.Net;
           using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

           namespace Unit.Tests.Controllers
           {
               /// <summary>
               /// Summary description for ControllerTest
               /// </summary>
               [TestClass]
               public class ControllerTest
               {
                   private TestController _testController;       
                   [TestInitialize]
                   public void estAPI_Initializer()
                   {
                       _testController = new TestController();
                       var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
                       System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
                       request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 1232141241");
                       request.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
                       _testController.Request = request;
                       _testController.Configuration = configuration;            
                   }

                   [TestCategory("Unit test")]
                   [TestMethod]
                   public async Task API_Async_Controller_Test()
                   {
                       IHttpActionResult asyncResponse = await _testController.StartTest();
                       var cToken = new System.Threading.CancellationToken(true);           
                       var rResult = asyncResponse.ExecuteAsync(cToken);                      
                       Assert.IsNotNull(rResult);
                       Assert.IsNotNull(rResult.Result);
                       Assert.AreEqual(rResult.Result.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK);
                       Assert.IsNotNull(rResult.Result.Content);
                       var rContent = rResult.Result.Content;

                       string data = await rContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
                       Assert.IsNotNull(data);
                       JavaScriptSerializer JSserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                       var finalResult = JSserializer.Deserialize<TestResult>(data);

                       Assert.IsNotNull(finalResult);
                       Assert.IsTrue(finalResult.Success);
                   }        
               }
           }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a general solution for calling some action and getting `HttpResponseMessage` as `Dictionary` which is very convenient for usage.

First some extension for the `dictionary`:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void AddRange<T, S>(this Dictionary<T, S> source,
                                      Dictionary<T, S> collection) 
    {
        if (collection == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Collection is null");
        }

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            source.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now request creating part:

```
public class RequestCreator
{
    protected static void FirstPart(ApiController controller,
                                    HttpMethod method,String actionUrl)
    {
        // Creating basic request message with message type and requesting 
        // url example : 'http://www.someHostName/UrlPath/'
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, actionUrl);

        // Adding configuration for request
        controller.Request.Properties.
          Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey,new HttpConfiguration());                                         
    }

    protected static Dictionary<String, Object> SecondPart
                                                 (HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        // Adding basic response content to dictionary
        var resultCollection = new Dictionary<String, Object>
        {
            {"StatusCode",response.StatusCode},
            {"Headers",response.Headers},
            {"Version",response.Version},
            {"RequestMessage",response.RequestMessage},
            {"ReasonPhrase",response.ReasonPhrase},
            {"IsSuccessStatusCode",response.IsSuccessStatusCode}
        };

        var responseContent = response.Content;
        // If response has content then parsing it and 
        // getting content properties
        if (null != responseContent)
        {
            var resultMessageString = response.Content.
                                               ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            resultCollection.AddRange((new JavaScriptSerializer()).
                                       DeserializeObject(resultMessageString) 
                                               as Dictionary<String, Object>);
        }


        return resultCollection;
    }       
}
```

And finally response message to dictionary converter `class`:

```
public class HttpResponseModelGetter : RequestCreator
{
    public Dictionary<String, Object>
                 GetActionResponse(ApiController controller,HttpMethod method,
                          String actionUrl,Func<HttpResponseMessage> callBack)
    {
        FirstPart(controller, method, actionUrl);
        var response = callBack();
        return SecondPart(response);
    }
}

public class HttpResponseModelGetter<T> : RequestCreator
{
    public Dictionary<String, Object> 
             GetActionResponse(ApiController controller,HttpMethod method,
                String actionUrl,Func<T,HttpResponseMessage> callBack,T param) 
    {
        FirstPart(controller, method, actionUrl);
        var response = callBack(param);
        return SecondPart(response);
    }
}

public class HttpResponseModelGetter<T1,T2> : RequestCreator
{
    public Dictionary<String, Object> 
        GetActionResponse(ApiController controller,HttpMethod method, 
             String actionUrl,Func<T1,T2,HttpResponseMessage> callBack,
             T1 param1,T2 param2)


    {
        FirstPart(controller, method, actionUrl);
        var response = callBack(param1,param2);
        return SecondPart(response);
    }
} 
//and so on...
```

and usage :

```
var responseGetter = new HttpResponseModelGetter();
var result = responseGetter.GetActionResponse(controller,HttpMethod.Get,
                    "http://localhost/Project/api/MyControllerApi/SomeApiMethod",
                                              controller.SomeApiMethod);

Boolean isComplete = Boolean.Parse(result["isComplete"].ToString());
```