# need to create convention for ApiControllers

Tags: c#, autofixture

I have a set of working imperative code in test and I'm trying to boil it down to an essential test convention.

My test looks like the following:

```
[Theory, BasicConventions]
public void GetVersionOnSiteVersionControllerReturnsASiteVersion(IFixture fixture)
{
    fixture.OmitAutoProperties = true;
    SiteVersion expected = fixture.Create<SiteVersion>();
    SiteVersion actual = null;

    var sut = fixture.Create<SiteVersionController>();

    var response = sut
        .GetSiteVersion()
        .ExecuteAsync(new CancellationToken())
        .Result
        .TryGetContentValue<SiteVersion>(out actual);

    actual.AsSource().OfLikeness<SiteVersion>().ShouldEqual(expected);
}
```

I also have a customization that allows this to work, namely by setting the `HttpConfiguration` and `HttpRequestMessage` to default non-null values.

```
public class ApiControllerCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        var origin = fixture.OmitAutoProperties;
        fixture.OmitAutoProperties = true;
        var sut = fixture.Create<SiteVersionController>();
        sut.Configuration = fixture.Create<HttpConfiguration>();
        sut.Request = fixture.Create<HttpRequestMessage>();
        fixture.Inject<SiteVersionController>(sut);
        fixture.OmitAutoProperties = origin;
    }
}
```

First, this looks ugly, but if I use Build<>().omit().with(config).with(request), it shuts off the automoq customization which it needs to build those instances.

Second, this only works for a SiteVersionController.  I'd much rather generalize this for all my ApiControllers (maybe that's a bad idea, but I won't know until I try).

Essentially my convention would be as follows:
**for all ApiControllers, create them without auto properties but do set the http configuration and request message properties to default non-null values**

Comment: What `ApiController` type are you working with? ASP.NET Web API? Which version?

Comment: My NuGet package manager says ASP.NET Web API Version 5.0.0

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19908385/126014

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ApiControllers` are quite difficult to wire up, because you'll need to assign certain properties to them in order for everything to work. At the very least, you'll need the `Request` property to be assigned, because otherwise, the `Controller` can't invoke `Request.CreateResponse`. Thus, switching off auto-properties for `ApiController` instances isn't a good strategy. Instead, you can configure AutoFixture to wire up `HttpRequestMessage` instances correctly.

**Web API 1**

With ASP.NET Web API 1, I usually use a Customization like this:

```
public class WebApiCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<HttpRequestMessage>(c => c
            .Do(x =>
                x.Properties.Add(
                    HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey,
                    new HttpConfiguration())));
    }
}
```

Since auto-properties are on by default, this is going to assign an appropriate instance of `HttpRequestMessage` to `ApiController.Request`. Together with an [Auto-mocking](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container) Customization, `Fixture` can now create instances of all your `ApiController` classes.

**Web API 2**

With ASP.NET Web API 2 (5.0.0.0), things are a little more complicated, but with a bit of trial and error, I got this Customization to pass 808 tests:

```
public class WebApiCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<HttpConfiguration>(c => c
            .OmitAutoProperties());
        fixture.Customize<HttpRequestMessage>(c => c
            .Do(x =>
                x.Properties.Add(
                    HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey,
                    fixture.Create<HttpConfiguration>())));
        fixture.Customize<HttpRequestContext>(c => c
            .Without(x => x.ClientCertificate));
    }
}
```

**Conventions**

If you package that into an `[AutoData]` attribute, you should be able to refactor your test to:

```
[Theory, BasicConventions]
public void GetVersionOnSiteVersionControllerReturnsASiteVersion(
    SiteVersionController sut,
    SiteVersion expected)
{
    SiteVersion actual = null;

    var response = sut
        .GetSiteVersion()
        .ExecuteAsync(new CancellationToken())
        .Result
        .TryGetContentValue<SiteVersion>(out actual);

    actual.AsSource().OfLikeness<SiteVersion>().ShouldEqual(expected);
}
```

Comment: this is great. Question, thankfully, I'm getting the hang of AutoFixture, most of my hangups are trying to wire things like this. How do you go about researching this, a strategy? or just experience?

Comment: Well, personally, I *wrote* AutoFixture, so you could say I'm cheating :) I invite others to answer this question, too.

Comment: The same customization for ASP.NET Web API 2 in F# can be found at: https://gist.github.com/moodmosaic/2789ba06980880217df7